# Creating a database of MDB extension using Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a resolute unyielding need to create an mdb database for a client of mine.
I am tearing my head over this, but I am not getting anywhere.

I have access to these tools

1. Microsoft Access 2007 ( creates db of the format .accdb )
2. Open Office Base 3.3 ( creates database of the format ODF Database )

I need to use it in my .NET application and I need it to be opened in Outlook 2003.

Plus this I have a visual studio 2010 ultimate. Can it help me with this requirement?
Is there a way online or using these tools in my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do.  Create your database in Access 2007 and save.  Then click the Office Button in the upper left and choose "Save As".

[image]

You can choose between older versions of Access - choosing Access 2002-2003 will save the file in MDB format.  You can repeat this process after you edit your 2007/ACCDB file, or you can open the .MDB file in 2007 and work with it directly.

(In your original question title, and again in your later comment, you mention "Outlook".  I'm assuming you meant Access in both cases!)

Comment: I'm running access 2007 version 14.0.6129.5000 (32 bit) and I don't have any other file-type options under "Save As"